# Arduino ligths on/off clapping hands

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm new to Arduino and I'd like to realize a system using Arduino One and SparkFun Electret Microphone Breakout (BOB-09964) to turn on/off lights clapping my hands. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9964

What are the components I need? I'm going to buy them and I don't want to buy components which I will not use soon (so no starter kits but only a breadboard, resistors, LEDs, etc...).

Sorry for this basic question but as I said I'm new to this world.

Answer (score 1):

If you start from the beginning of the project, instead of trying to jump in half way through, you'll know precisely what components you need.

Your first step shouldn't be trying to order components, but to identify (through research) how the technology works.

Second is to find out how it can be implemented, by looking at existing schematics and designs that other people have created.

Third is to design your own schematic.

Fourth is to prototype it.  It's only at this stage that you should be thinking about what components to order.

Go back to stage one and do the research. Thanks to the likes of Google it'll probably only take you a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

See the Arduino tutorial for a [Sound Sensor Example](http://www.arduino.org/learning/tutorials/boards-tutorials/sound-sensor-example).

This is a very similar project that shows the breadboard layout and code needed for a clapping sensor based on an electret microphone breakout board.

The website listed above has a list of parts needed, the circuit diagram as well as the code needed.

Comment: I was able to get this project working. I built just the sound sensor side, and used the onboard LED instead of building an LED circuit. At first I had problems getting a clear analog signal, due to poor connections to the microphone breakout board. After soldering the header pins to the breakout board the connection was good and the system worked.